# Detect changes within file at location

Tags: java, file, monitoring, inotify

I know that it's possible to detect changes to a file, such as using the Linux inotify service, or something like the Java 7 WatchService.

However, what I wish to do is to not only detect that a file has changed, but also where within the file the change occurred.

I don't think there is any existing OS service, or native language API for achieving this (maybe I'm wrong), so I'm wondering if anyone could offer any advice on doing this.

For example, let's start off small with say a 1MB file, that could be randomly altered at any given file offset.  Can anyone offer any advice on attempting to monitor the file for change, as well as determining where within the file the change occurred.

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't think `java.io` or OS provide any service like that. You have to read and compare the whole file. Maybe divide the file to multiple segments and compare the md5sum digest would be getter.

Comment: Wouldn't that require that there be a copy of the file kept that could be compared against the changed file to see where there are differences?

Comment: How about checking your file to git and do `git status` whenever you want to know if it changes? `git diff` will tell you exactly what's changed -- assuming it's a text file

Comment: I'm guessing git can only do this on text files, not binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep 2 copies of the file and monitor the main one with OS monitor and when that fires do a binary diff (is it a binary file?) with the backup - see here for binary diff method
https://superuser.com/a/125408

Comment: It is a binary file yes. That should work ok for smallish files, but I don't think it would scale very well.  Say if the file was a gigabyte or so in size.  Good idea though!